# Free Build Server Service for opensource projects?

Tags: service, open-source, hudson, cloud, jenkins

Does anyone know of a free build server service to coincide with scm/forum/issue tracking services such as sourceforge/googlecode?

Obviously hudson/jenkins service would be my first preference related to primarily java/maven2, but anything would be nice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloudbees has an [offering for FOSS projects](http://cloudbees.com/foss/).

Another one (especially for public Github repos): http://travis-ci.org/

Comment: Cloudbees no longer has a FOSS offering.

Comment: The offering seems still active according to their website.

Comment: Please provide link, @dunni

Answer (score 0):

Researching the same thing currently, I stumbled over jenkinshosting.com (reported as suspicious site, Aug2012)- Jenkins build server, free for FOSS. Haven't tried it yet, though.

Comment: This site is indicated as malicious by Google.

Comment: Thx for the hint, I edited the answer. Maybe they got hacked or somesuch.

Comment: This site looks dead. Look at their blog: http://blog.jenkinshosting.com/ - it's empty as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian offers licensed and on-demand products to open-source projects. Bamboo may be included.
https://www.atlassian.com/software/views/open-source-license-request

Answer (score 0):

A TeamCity based server farm is available for open source projects through http://teamcity.codebetter.com/.  Read the [announcement](http://codebetter.com/codebetter-ci/).

Another option for OSS is http://www.appveyor.com/, which is including support for  Windows 8.1 store apps.

Answer (score 0):

[Jenkinshosting.com](http://jenkinshosting.com) use to offer free open source hosting. It's worth checking out to see if it's still continued.

Comment: checked today. cheapest I see there is $49/mo